# How to create multiple pages in Webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, pug, webpack-dev-server

This may seem like an amateur questions but I am having trouble creating other pages with Webpack

Here is my webpack.config.js file

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
var HtmlWebpackHarddiskPlugin = require('html-webpack-harddisk-plugin')
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var path = require('path')

var isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' // true or false
var cssDev = ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
var cssProd = ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
  fallback: 'style-loader',
  loader: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
  publicPath: '/dist'
})
var cssConfig = isProd ? cssProd : cssDev

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/app.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: 'eslint-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: cssConfig
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        use: 'pug-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    compress: true,
    hot: true,
    open: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Project Demo',
      hash: true,
      alwaysWriteToDisk: true,
      template: './src/index.pug'
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackHarddiskPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: 'app.css',
      disable: !isProd,
      allChunks: true
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin()
  ]
}
```

Basically, my config file is currently uses `HtmlWebpackPlugin` to **input** my `index.pug` from the `src` folder then **outputs** `index.html` into the `dist` folder.

However, what if I want to create different pages? For example, an about page.

I know that if I create a `about.pug` in my `src` folder, it will not be processed by Webpack because I have included it in my configuration file. However, I am not sure how to accomplish this.

How could I **input** different pug files such as `about.pug` `gallery.pug` `contact.pug` in my `src` folder then have all these **output** in my `dist` folder as `about.html` `gallery.html` `contact.html`

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned by @Derek you can programmatically generate the list of `HtmlWebpackPlugin` instances.

```
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')

// Store .html file names in src/ in an array
const pages =
  fs
    .readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'))
    .filter(fileName => fileName.endsWith('.html'))

module.exports = {
  // Use .map() on the array of file names to map each file name
  // to the plugin instance, then spread the mapped array into
  // the plugins array.
  plugins: [
    ...pages.map(page => new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: page,
      filename: page
    }))
  ]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can create multiple instances of `HtmlWebpackPlugin`:

```
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Project Demo',
      hash: true,
      alwaysWriteToDisk: true,
      template: './src/index.pug'
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Page2',
      hash: true,
      alwaysWriteToDisk: true,
      template: './src/page2.pug'
    }),
...
```

Comment: There is no way to include an entire directory though?

Comment: Don't think so it can. I can't access GitHub with my company network but found this from googling https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#generating-multiple-html-files

Comment: Or you can write a loop to generate the array.

Comment: The webpack config is just a JavaScript file, so you can read a directory and programmatically generate the list of `HtmlWebpackPlugin` entries based on the contents of the directory.